# Get the mouse Position every X seconds

Tags: c#, timer

I'm trying to get the position(x,y) of my mouse every 5 seconds  so I use this code to get it

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct POINT
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;
    public static implicit operator Point(POINT point)
    {
        return new Point(point.X, point.Y);
    }
}         

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool GetCursorPos(out POINT lpPoint);   
public static Point GetCursorPosition()
{
    POINT lpPoint;
    GetCursorPos(out lpPoint);
    return lpPoint;
}
```

but then I must run this method to get the new position of the mouse so I found this code that I have no idea how to use it:

```
 var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(
        e => Mymethode(),  
        null, 
        TimeSpan.Zero, 
        TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
```

how can I use this code together to show (console) the position every 5 seconds

Comment: If winforms you can just use `Control.MousePosition`

Comment: Do you have a GUI (like WinForms or WPF) or are you trying to catch the mouse wherever it is on the screen?

Comment: No Winform , just console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
        var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(
            e =>
            {
                var p = GetCursorPosition();
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("X: {0}, Y: {1}", p.X, p.Y));
            },
            null,
            TimeSpan.Zero,
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
```

You just need to call `GetCursorPosition` in your timer callback and then do whatever you want with the value.

Here's a complete working console app that will display the cursor position every 5 seconds until you hit enter:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct POINT
        {
            public int X;
            public int Y;
        }
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool GetCursorPos(out POINT lpPoint);
        public static POINT GetCursorPosition()
        {
            POINT lpPoint;
            GetCursorPos(out lpPoint);
            return lpPoint;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(
                e =>
                {
                    var p = GetCursorPosition();
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("X: {0}, Y: {1}", p.X, p.Y));
                },
                null,
                TimeSpan.Zero,
                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Note I took out the part converting the struct `POINT` to `Point`, but you can put that back in. It wasn't clear which `Point` you were using there.

Comment: it works but the program exit without displaying anything ! even when I add console.ReadKey()

Comment: @user3708197: I've posted a complete working console application. You should be able to adapt it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Timers.Timer GetMousePosition = new System.Timers.Timer();
GetMousePosition.Interval=5000;
GetMousePosition.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(GetMousePosition_Elapsed);

void GetMousePosition_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
  POINT CursorPositon= GetCursorPosition()
  textBox1.AppentText("Cursor is in X Coordinate: "+CursorPositon.X.ToString()+" and Y-Coordinate "+ CursorPositon.X.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you want is just a timer tick event that every 5 seconds calls your "GetCursorPos" and prints the position of your mouse.

Try something like the following:

```
Timer clock = new Timer();
        clock.Interval = 5000; //Miliseconds
        clock.Tick += clock_Tick;
        clock.Start();
```

And in you clock_Tick:

```
void clock_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.Writeline(GetCursorPos());
    }
```